# Print matrix to pdf in R

Tags: r, pdf, matrix

I would like to know if there is any R package that allows for "pretty" printing of matrices/dataframes to pdf: by "pretty", I mean being able to print a matrix with brackets to a pdf:

[image]

Comment: the `latex` command in the `Hmisc` package might get you close; is using LaTeX as an intermediate stage acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, that's definitely acceptable! I am not sure how to make this `latex` command work.. I get the error: `'latex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: you would need to install the `Hmisc` package first, then load it with `library()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hand-rolled solution that outputs a matrix to an `array` environment in a standalone LaTeX file; you may be able to customize `Hmisc::latex` for better results.

```
m <- matrix(c(23,5,2,34,4,4,3,4,26),
             byrow=TRUE,ncol=3)
unlink("outfile.tex")  ## danger
ff <- file("outfile.tex",open="a")
writeLines(c("\\documentclass{article}",
             "\\begin{document}",
             "$$",
             "\\left(",
             "\\begin{array}{ccc}"),
             con=ff)
write.table(m,sep=" & ", eol="\\\\", row.names=FALSE,
            col.names=FALSE,append=TRUE,
            file=ff)
writeLines(c("\\end{array}",
             "\\right)",
             "$$",
             "\\end{document}"),
           con=ff)
close(ff)
```

With a little bit of extra work this could be generalized to a function that recognized the number of columns in the matrix, took an output file name as an argument, etc. -- but it might be reinventing part of `Hmisc::latex()`.

Comment: Thanks Ben. What if I have already generated the Latex code using `xtable`: `library(xtable) xtab = xtable(m) print(xtab, floating=FALSE, tabular.environment="bmatrix", hline.after=NULL, include.rownames=FALSE, include.colnames=FALSE)`. How can I just print this code to pdf?
`

Comment: I would also need to write to a `pdf` file.. Can I replace the `tex` file by a `pdf` file?

Comment: OK, then `xtable` is really the answer to your question -- it does the same as my code above.  My code, and `xtable`, assume that you're going to run the file through LaTeX as an intermediate stage.  You can use `tools::texi2pdf()` from within R to convert LaTeX to PDF, but you need to have the LaTeX tools installed on your computer.